# Jemboss failed to launch

Tags: java

I installed Jemboss with apt, aptitude, synaptic on Focal (and Impish):

> lsb_release -rd Description:  Ubuntu 21.10 Release:   21.10
>
> apt-cache policy jemboss jemboss:   Installed: 6.6.0+dfsg-9ubuntu1
> Candidate: 6.6.0+dfsg-9ubuntu1   Version table:  ***
> 6.6.0+dfsg-9ubuntu1 500
> 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 Packages
> 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 Packages
> 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

```
apt install jemboss
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless dialign emboss emboss-data emboss-lib fonts-dejavu-extra java-common
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libhpdf-2.3.0 openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless primer3
Suggested packages:
  emboss-doc emboss-test embassy clustalw fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei | fonts-wqy-zenhei ncbi-epcr
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless dialign emboss emboss-data emboss-lib fonts-dejavu-extra java-common jemboss
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libhpdf-2.3.0 openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless primer3
0 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 113 MB of archives.
After this operation, 684 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

When I launch it fails with these errors:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.14.1" 2022-02-08
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.14.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.14.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)

brad@rudy:/etc/emboss$ jemboss
brad@rudy:/etc/emboss$ Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1914)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.base/java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:455)
    at org.emboss.jemboss.JembossParams.checkDesktopSupport(JembossParams.java:1408)
    at org.emboss.jemboss.JembossParams.<init>(JembossParams.java:352)
    at org.emboss.jemboss.Jemboss.<init>(Jemboss.java:102)
    at org.emboss.jemboss.Jemboss.main(Jemboss.java:397)
```

UPDATE: suddenly jEmboss started with no errors, thanks guys!
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emboss/+bug/1968178

Comment: Was jemboss installed via `apt` or another means? 

Comment: jemboss installed via apt

Comment: @matigo do you have any clues?